# Compiler Crash with C++ Array

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am new to c++(background in java) and am having a weird issue with arrays.
I have the following code involving rolling a dice, the array is to store previous rolls.

```
#include <stdlib.h> //c file for random number generator
#include <iostream>
#include "Dice.h";

using namespace std;

int previousTurns[10];
int count = 0;
void Dice::roll()
{
   cout<<"Rolling Dice....";
   int seed = rand() %100;
   srand(seed);
   int roll = rand() %6 + 1;
   cout<<"You have rolled a " << roll << "\n";
   previousTurns[count] = roll;
   count++;
}
```

I also have a header file Dice.h(that includes other methods I have not implemented yet):

```
#ifndef DICE_H_
#define DICE_H_

class Dice
{
   private:
      int previousTurns[10];
      int count;
      void extendArray(int a[]); 
      int size();
   public:
      void roll();
      void previousRolls();
      void displayArray();
};
#endif /* DICE_H_ */
```

All of this code works except for the line "previousTurns[count] = roll", the compiler crashes once it reaches this line with no error what so ever.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Can you create a [mcve] please?

Comment: He probably meant his app crashes

Comment: How many times are you rolling....?

Comment: @AndyG, that method is not of importance for this issue,it is a method I will implement to mimic the vector class(ie arraylist)

Comment: Are you safely checking for the range before accessing elements in this line `previousTurns[count]; count++;`?

Comment: you have `previousTurns` and `count` twice each, once in the class and once as globals declared in the source file. Shouldnt be the problem here, but at least it is confusing

Comment: I rolled 3 times for 2 different dice objects

Comment: ...,maybe it is the problem. You initialize `count`, but do you initialize `Dice::count` ? If you dont then `previousTurns[count]` is undefined behaviour

Comment: Part of a good solution for you will be to use **`std::vector`**. That `extendArray` looks ominous. Voted to close as lacking reproducible example.

Comment: @JmanxC A side note: `seed()` should be called only once and not for every call of `roll()`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I second you on the 'extendArray'  since it doesn't return anything and takes a copy of the array, money says it's not doing what the OP thinks it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your source file you have

```
int previousTurns[10];
int count = 0;
```

those are different from `previousTurns` and `count` members of `Dice`. Actually they are completely unrelated variables that just happen to have the same name. The member `count` on the other hand is used uninitialized here:

```
 previousTurns[count] = roll;
```

Note that in the member function it is the member `count`, not the one from `int count = 0;`. You should initalize it in the constructor, something like this:

```
Dice::Dice() : count(0) {}
```

Also note that you should call `seed` only once (eg in the constructor) and not each time you roll a number.

Comment: Ah i see, so you do not need to define the variables defined in the header file again? For example i can initalize count = 0 in the header file then use Dice::count in the source file? That is Dice::count is not the same as count(treated as different variables)

Comment: ..of course it is different from Java. No offense, but if you think you can enter c++ at a medium level, because you know java, then you are on the wrong track.

Comment: Cool, is there a way to include cpp files,ie make classes without header files to avoid this naming convention issue(ie Dice::count vs count), or is that bad practice in c++

Comment: @JmanxC I dont understand the issue. You dont need the `int count = 0;` in the source file at all

Comment: Yes I now know I don't, I have removed count from the file, as I included .h in my main driver program, I have included those variable definitions in my header file. My question is, is it possible to create a class file without a header file(that is define the class in the .cpp file instead) and include that .cpp file in the main driver program. This will allow me to use "int count" rather than "Dice::count", or is it bad practice to include cpp files rather then .h files.

Comment: @JmanxC sorry, but I cannot follow you. Why do you want to use `int count;` ? `int count;` will always declare a new variable and cannot refer to a member (unless it is part of the class declaration itself)

Comment: Probably over complicating my question, my question is can u declare the class itself in the cpp file rather then the header file. In that case you would be able to use count as so rather then the syntax Dice::count correct? My question then is can you #include cpp files in the main driver file rather then .h files or is this bad practice?

Comment: @JmanxC sorry, still dont get it. In member functions you can use `count` (nobody would ever write `Dice::count`). Anyhow, no you dont include source files.